# Why it doesn't store unless when I trying to set a name for a radio button during change?

Tags: c#, winforms

I apologize for the newbie question. So I have 3 radio buttons in my windows form application where the user selects one of them. I have these 3 in a group box and attempted to identify it as a string and use it in a message box later in my code.

```
string NAME;
if (radiobutton1.checked == true){
  NAME = radiobutton1.Text;
}
else if (radiobutton2.Checked == true) {
NAME = radiobutton2.Text;
}
```

Then I have a button which displays the message:

```
message box.show("Welcome " + NAME + "How are you?");
```

The output of this is welcome how are you instead of welcome Bob how are you? unless I have selected one radio button then changed and pressed a different one. Can someone please explain what is happening here and why it is only displaying the name if the radio button is changed?

Comment: RadioButton.Checked doesn't register until a button is selected. You can set this programmatically by adding "checked=true" to one of the radio buttons, or in codebehind.

Comment: Where is the first code situated? - The best way to code this is a __common__ handler for __all_ your RadioButtons in the group: `rb_CheckChanged((object sender, EventArgs e) {TEXT =  ((RadioButton)sender).Text;`

Comment: You should use this logic in CheckedChanged Event of these RadioButtons.

Comment: yeah so what I'm saying is if i select radio button 1 and then press the button it doesn't display the name but then if i keep the form open and press radio button 2 and press the button again it will display the name from radiobutton1?

Answer (score 0):

Might be this code helps you

```
   string value = "";
   bool isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
   if(isChecked )
   value=radioButton1.Text;
   else
   value=radioButton2.Text;

   MessageBox.show("Welcome " + value + "How are you?");
```

Comment: This works for 2 radio buttons but how do you implement 3 to it? add another bool?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you can set the 'checked' property to true in property box for your default radio button.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, name stays empty as long as no radiobutton is selected.
Try it like this:

```
string name = null;

if( radiobutton1.Checked )
    name = radiobutton1.Text;
else if( radiobutton2.Checked )
    name = radiobutton2.Text;
else if( radiobutton3.Checked )
    name = radiobutton3.Text;

if( name != null )
    MessageBox.Show( "Welcome " + name + ". How are you?" );
else
    MessageBox.Show( "Please select a name!" );
```